# Are relatively prime rational integers still relatively prime in quadratic fields?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If m and n are relatively prime rational (standard) integers, must they be 
relatively prime in every quadratic field Q[$\sqrt{d}$]?

Comment: Think of norms!

Comment: i tried using contradictions with norms but i couldnt figure it out, do you mind writing out a partial-whole solution or just a hint?

Comment: You don't need to think about norms; use Bezout's lemma.

Comment: or think of the fact that the ideal $(m,n)=(1)$

Comment: we havent learned about Bezout's lemma yet

Comment: It's just the Euclidean algorithm. If $m$ and $n$ are any positive integers, then there are integers $a$ and $b$ so that $am+bn=d$, where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$. This has the advantage of working in any ring containing the integers.

Comment: If noninteger $\sqrt k$ divides an integer $n$ then $k$ divides $n$.  So if $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime then $\sqrt{k}$ can only divide at most one of $n$ or $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $a+b\sqrt d$ divides both $n$ and $m$. Say, $(a+b\sqrt d)(x+y\sqrt d)=m$ and $(a+b\sqrt d)(u+v\sqrt d)=n$. As the irrational parts $(ay+bx)\sqrt d$, $(av+bu)\sqrt d$ must be zero, then also $(a-b\sqrt d)(x-y\sqrt d)=m$ and $(a-b\sqrt d)(u-v\sqrt d)=n$. After multiplication of the two variants,
$(a^2-db^2)(x^2-dy^2)=m^2$ and $(a^2-db^2)(u^2-dv^2)=n^2$. As $m^2,n^2$ are also co-prime, we conclude $a^2-db^2=\pm1$, i.e., $a+b\sqrt d$ is a unit.

Comment: this is the full solution?

Comment: @EricMaynard If you need to ask that then you probably need more study time on the basics...

Comment: BTW, +1.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I understand the solution @DonAntonio, but if you looked above, I asked for a hint or a solution so I was just making sure that I didn't miss something.